# kendo combobox giving error while enabling and disabling

Tags: combobox, kendo-ui

I am using kendo combobox. I have written below code to enable and disable combobox

```
  function enableDisableFrameworkAndAltFrameworkVersion(platformVersion) {

        var comboBox = $("#selFrameworkVersion").data("kendoComboBox");

        if (platformVersion === 1 ) {
            comboBox.enable(false);

        }
    }
```

But this code gives me error as "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'enable' of undefined "

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Now i followed one example on this link below
[Disable kendo combo](http://rniemeyer.github.com/knockout-kendo/web/ComboBox.html)

So now i changed code in my html and added enabled parameter to kendo combobox like below

```
<input  id="selFrameworkVersion" data-bind="kendoComboBox: { dataTextField: 'Name', dataValueField: 'Id', data:  $root.versionListByProductType, value:  $root.editFrameworkVersion, enabled: enableFrameWorkCombo} />
```

In my view model i declare one observable like below

```
self.enableFrameWorkCombo = ko.observable(true);
```

Then changed my function like below

```
function enableDisableFrameworkAndAltFrameworkVersion(platformVersion) {

    var comboBox = $("#selFrameworkVersion").data("kendoComboBox");

    if (platformVersion === 1 ) {
        $('#multiAltVersion').attr("disabled", true);
        //comboBox.enable(false);
        self.enableFrameWorkCombo(false);
        return;
    }
    else if (platformVersion === 2 || platformVersion === 3) {
        //comboBox.enable(true);
        self.enableFrameWorkCombo(true);
        $('#multiAltVersion').attr("disabled", true);
    }
    else {
        //comboBox.enable(true);
        self.enableFrameWorkCombo(true);
        $('#multiAltVersion').attr("disabled", false);
    }
}
```

Now it gives me error

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: enableFrameWorkCombo is not defined;
Bindings value: kendoComboBox: { dataTextField: 'Name', dataValueField: 'Id', data: $root.versionListByProductType, value:  $root.editFrameworkVersion, enabled: enableFrameWorkCombo, optionsCaption: 'Please select Version...' }
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Please help me someone

Comment: Anyone there? Please help me. Banging head against the walls :(

Answer (score 1):

The fact that is shows `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'enable' of undefined "` while executing:

```
function enableDisableFrameworkAndAltFrameworkVersion(platformVersion) {
    var comboBox = $("#selFrameworkVersion").data("kendoComboBox");
    if (platformVersion === 1 ) {
        comboBox.enable(false);
    }
}
```

means that `comboBox` is `undefined`. Since it is the result of computing `$("#selFrameworkVersion").data("kendoComboBox")` means that there is an HTML element with id `selFrameworkVersion` but it is not a `kendoComboBox`.

Please, check that when you invoke this function, `kendoComboBox` is actually initialized.

**EDIT:**

The following example (running on http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/qtaAS/) enables / disable a ComboBox using above function...

```
function enableDisableFrameworkAndAltFrameworkVersion(platformVersion) {
        var comboBox = $("#selFrameworkVersion").data("kendoComboBox");
        console.log("combobox", comboBox);
        if (platformVersion === 1) {
            comboBox.enable(false);
        } else {
            comboBox.enable(true);
        }
    }

    var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        data                : [
            { "Id": 1, "Name": "node1" },
            { "Id": 2, "Name": "node2" },
            { "Id": 3, "Name": "node3" },
            { "Id": 4, "Name": "node4" },
            { "Id": 5, "Name": "node5" }
        ],
        enableFrameWorkCombo: function () {
            alert("hello");
        }
    });

    $("#disable").on("click", function () {
        enableDisableFrameworkAndAltFrameworkVersion(1);
    });
    $("#enable").on("click", function () {
        enableDisableFrameworkAndAltFrameworkVersion(2);
    });

    kendo.bind($("#selFrameworkVersion"), viewModel);
```

And the HTML is:

```
<div><a href="#" id="disable" class="k-button">Disable</a></div>
<div><a href="#" id="enable" class="k-button">Enable</a></div>

<input id="selFrameworkVersion"
       data-role="combobox"
       data-text-field="Name"
       data-value-field="Id"
       value="2"
       data-bind="source : data, enabled: enableFrameWorkCombo"/>
```

Comment: if that is the case then it should also not load data in combobox? Am i correct?

Comment: What I say is about the order on how the things happen. It might load the data but after running this function. I can only see one small part of the code but if the console says `undefined` does not have `enable` and the only `enable` that I see is applied to something called `comboBox` then `comboBox` needs to be `undefined`.

Comment: how and where to define it? Please tell me.

Comment: Invoke `$("#selFrameworkVersion").kendoComboBox({...})` and the next instruction in your code invoke the function `enableDisableFrameworkAndAltFrameworkVersion`. Is that possible?

Comment: if i try to call function enableDisableFrameworkAndAltFrameworkVersion inside the code you mentioned then it gives error as 'get', 'set' or property name followed by ':' expected

Comment: i am still struggling. Please help me.